# downloading a page without downloading image files or css or javascript with curl

Tags: php, curl

Whenever i use `curl(php)` to download a page it downloads everything on the page like `images, css files or javascript files`. but sometimes i dont want to download these. can i control the resources that i download through curl. i have gone through the manual but i havent found an option that can make this happen? Please dont suggest getting the whole page and then using some `regex` magic because that would still download the page and increase load time.
this is a demo code where i download a page from `mozilla.com`

```
<?php
$url="http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/";
$userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
//$accept="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$encoding="gzip, deflate";
$header['lang']="en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header['charset']="ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header['conn']="keep-alive";
$header['keep-alive']=115;

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,$encoding);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
$content=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
?>
```

when i echo the content it shows the images too. i saw in `firebug's network tab` that images and `external js` files are being downloaded

Comment: Could you provide us some code?

Comment: Provided you mean external css/js files, not inline css/js, cURL shouldn't be doing this. Could you show us the code you're using at the moment?

Comment: You're viewing it in a browser... and you wonder why the BROWSER is fetching external resources? Curl only fetched the HTML. it's your BROWSER doing the images and css and js.

Comment: @Marc B: i got your point but how do i find out that what is being downloaded with curl?

Comment: @Marc B: i got it. i checked `CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE ` to see that it is returning only `text/html`. also i used `CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD ` and got the size around 25 kB and there is no way i could get all images and js in 25 kB. thanks

Comment: curl downloads ONLY the html, which you are then outputting to your browser. your BROWSER is then downloading everything else referred to in the page. Try outputting what you've curled with a `header('Content-type: text/plain')` so the browser won't parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's curl only fetches what you tell it to. It doesn't parse html to look for javascript/css `<link>` tags and `<img>` tags and doesn't fetch them automatically.

If you have curl downloading those resources, then it's your code telling it to do so, and it's up to you to decide what to fetch and what not to. Curl only does what you tell it to.

Comment: @KARASZI István: provide the code. there was some network problem due to which i couldnt edit my post

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid the download by using

```
echo htmlentities($content);
```